# Browser hanged while plotting more than 10000 series using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need your little help, I am working on a task where I have to plot maximum 10000 series on one chart. Every time I have random number of series like 1000, 1500 or 2000 up to 10000. I successfully put them in chart object but when i assign the data object to chart class my browser get hanged for couple of seconds. Here is my code,

```
var obj =  {
           credits: {
                 enabled: false
             },
           title: {
                         text: 'Sentiment Activity Of Stocks'
                     },
           chart: {
                     width: 1200
                     },
           exporting: {
                    enabled: false
           },

               xAxis: {
                   min: -5,
                   max:5,
                   title: {
                        enabled: true,
                        text: '<b>S Score</b>',
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'normal'
                        }
                    }
              },
               yAxis: {
                   title: {
                     enabled: true,
                     text: '<b>S Score</b>',
                     style: {
                         fontWeight: 'normal'
                     }
                 }

               },
           plotOptions: {
                         line: {
                             marker:{
                                 symbol:"circle"
                             }
                         },


                         },
           tooltip: {
               formatter: function () {

                    var x = this.x;
                    x = x.toFixed(4);

                    var y = this.y;
                       y = y.toFixed(4);

                      var delta = parseFloat(this.series.data[1].x-this.series.data[0].x);
                          delta = delta.toFixed(4);

                      return ' <b>'+ this.series.name +'<br/> <b>Score ( t ): </b>' + y +
                            '<br /> <b>Score(t-1): </b>' + x + '<br />'+
                            '<b>SDelta: </b>' + delta + '<br />'+
                          '<br/>';

               }
           },
               legend: {
                   enabled: false
               },
               series: [
               ]

  };


          $.each(parsedJson ,function(index, element) {
          var s_color = "Green";
          if(element.sdelta < 0)
             s_color = "red";

          var diffe  = parseFloat(element.sscore-element.sdelta);
          var sscore = exp_y = parseFloat(element.sscore);

          if(sscore > diffe){
              var arr =  {data: [[diffe,exp_y],[sscore, exp_y]],name:element.subject,color:s_color,id:element.subject};
          }else{
              var arr =  {data: [[sscore, exp_y],[diffe,exp_y]],name:element.subject,color:s_color,id:element.subject};
          }

          obj.series.push(arr);
        });

       $('#container').highcharts(obj);
```

I am not sure what is the actual reason behind browser hanging. Might be there is some limit on no. of series in one chart.  Your help is really appreciated for identifying the reason behind this problem.

Comment: What is the purposoe of using 10000 per single chart? How many points you have per serie?

Comment: @Sebastian. I only have two points in one series.

Answer (score 1):

There is an article on hith highcharts website about performance issues. You can read it here:

http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/48-loading-millions-of-points-in-highcharts

Some pointers for you to try:

1. Disable animations. This can really slow things down badly.
2. Try using highstock instead. Highstock can cope with larger data sets.

```
    chart: {
        animation: false
    },
```